# ListView.scrollTo(index) very slow

Tags: listview, javafx, scrollto

I use a `ListView` to display ~6500 items (files). If I call `scrollTo(index)` it takes about 650ms (=0.65s) in average. In my opinion this is very, very slow (It feels very laggy). Does somebody know if there is a much more efficient way to realize the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a jira ticket. This performance issue is fixed in JavaFX8.

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36183